# Get value of current Observable state

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, observable

So I am trying to get the value (the email) of my Observable<firebase.User>. I know there is something called BehaviourSubject, but I cannot use it since firebase.User requires an Observable, it seems.

```
retrieveUserData(){
    let emailVal = "";

    this.userData.subscribe(
      {
        next: x =>  emailVal += x.email  && console.log(x.email),
        error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
        complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
      }
    );
    return emailVal;
}
```

So my goal is to get **x.email** in the **emailVal let**, in order to pass it & display, for example.

The problem is, that I am getting an  (by logging the whole method retrieveUserData()), but the console.log(x.email) always returns the value I am looking for.

Why is that & is there a way to get the value & store it in a string, let or something else?

Comment: There is no initial value at the time your page loads.  You get a User object whenever the Firebase SDK delivers you one, and no sooner.  `currentUser` will be null until then.  You might want to read this blog post for more information about how the Firebase Auth APIs work.  You will have to adapt it to Angular.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Observables are async. It means when you run subscribe method of the observable, it runs the command without blocking the current runtime. Also, you are assigning the value of `emailVal` when the observable is run but you return the value without waiting for the assignment to be happened.

What you can do?

- You can keep a global variable to keep the email globally and use that variable to display the email in the html side.

  ```
  @Component({
      selector: "my-app",
      // See here, I used emailVal to display it
      template: "<span>{{emailVal}}</span>",
      styles: [""]
  })
  export class TestComponent {
        emailVal = "";

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.retrieveUserData();
        }

        retrieveUserData(): void {
            this.userData.subscribe(
                x => this.handleData(x.email),
                err => console.error("Observer got an error: " + err)
            );
        }

        handleData(email) {
            // Here, we assign the value of global variable (defined in class level)
            this.emailVal = email;
            console.log(email);
        }
  }
  ```
- You can use `rxjs` library in such a way to make the observable return the value and return the observable in the method as below

  ```
   retrieveUserData(): Observable<firebase.User> {
       return this.userData.pipe(
         map(x => x.email)
       );
   }
  ```

  And in html side, using async pipe (as an example):

  ```
  <span>{{retrieveUserData() | async}}</span>
  ```

  async pipe will subscribe to observable and wait for it to complete and then take the value and put it in the value of span. You can check [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ad8cqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to understand this method deeply.

Comment: When I log the retrieveUserData() method now, it returns me some type of Observable, which doesnt seem to be the desired "firebase.User", but it*should* return the email itself, a string, right? (Since x => x.email ?) Also the span, doesnt seem to do anything :-/

Comment: It is because we do not return the value itself in the method but instead we are returning an Observable that will give us the data in the end. In order to get the data out of an Observable, you need to subscribe to it (this will trigger the action defined in the Observable). I have edited my answer and added a working StackBlitz url. Also, I have described the first method with an example :)

Comment: The subscribe will throw an error, saying that "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'" on this.emailVal. (Altough both should be string...)

Comment: I think you are mixing the solutions. I offered you two **different** solutions. It is probably better for you to implement the first approach. In the first approach, I only did one thing: made the  `emailVal` a global variable. Then, you can access it in html-side. Did you try this?

Comment: I tried, yea. I am only using the first method, which seems to make sense, though. The error is gone now (I think that was something with the IDE), but still, emailVal seems to be "" and so it doesnt display anything. I will try again when I am home, with VS Code. Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, so pay attention to this line as well `next: x =>  this.emailVal = x.email  && console.log(x.email)` You are assigning the `this.emailVal` (the global variable) So it should work that way. If you encounter any issue, let me know. Otherwide, please don't forget to mark this answer as approved :)

Comment: So I am now on my main machine and I am getting following error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'. (on this.emailVal), using the first method.

Comment: Hi @alex.s sorry for the late reply, I updated the solution. I have tried, it works as intended. Can you please also check it?